# How to extract and manipulate text from docx file using python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, python-docx

I have a docx file which I converted into text using the docx2txt library.After that, I have to extract text in between.I used a regular expression for the task but it's just showing "[]"  as output.

```
import  docx2txt
import  re
te=docx2txt.process("y.docx")

n=re.findall(r'Reg(.*?)Reg',te)
print(n)
```

Comment: `re.findall(r'Reg(.*?)Reg',te, flags=re.DOTALL)`

Comment: Thankyou so much